# cairo_pdf uses Arial, not Helvetica

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, cairo

I would like to use a consistent typeface for my plots in a `knitr` document. Right now I am switching between `cairo_pdf` and `pdf`. The reason I am using `cairo_pdf` in some plots is to avoid en-dashes in certain circumstances. But when `cairo_pdf` is invoked on my system, I get an Arial font; whereas `pdf` uses Helvetica.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = 1, out.height = "1in", fig.width=1, out.width="1in")
@

<<pdf, dev='pdf'>>=
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x = 1, y = 1, geom = "blank") + 
  xlab("RQac")
@

<<cairo, dev='cairo_pdf'>>=
qplot(x = 1, y = 1, geom = "blank") + 
  xlab("RQac")
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to select the font (and not just Arial or Helvetica). However, I cannot install the `extrafonts` package.

```
install.packages("extrafonts")
```

results in a prompt for the installation of `Rttf2pt1` which fails to compile.

```
Warning: running command 'make --no-print-directory -f "Makefile.win"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rttf2pt1'
* removing 'C:/R/R-3.3.0/library/Rttf2pt1'
```

How can I use Arial font in every chunk? How can I use Helvetica in every chunk?

Comment: The help page for `cairo_pdf` says you should be looking at the "Cairo Fonts" section of the ?X11 page. Have you?

Comment: I don't see that cross-reference in the `cairo_pdf` help file. The Fonts section of `X11` seems to suggest that only Arial can be used (or Times or a monospaced font). Is that true?

Comment: The `family` item in the Usage section of ?cairo_pdf says "See, the ‘Cairo fonts’ section in the help for X11." Isn't that what I wrote??? Your reading of that section is also quite different than my reading. I don't see anything that says you are restricted in the choice of fonts.

Comment: Odd, `?cairo_pdf` for me says under the `family` item "one of the device-independent font families, "sans", "serif" and "mono", or a character string specify a font family to be searched for in a system-dependent way."

Comment: Windows versus *NIX, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows.

Comment: So, you apparently have the option of "a system-dependent search" for a named font family and should be seeking further information about your options in the documentation/

Answer (score 2):

The interim solution I had was to use the `showtext` package. The disadvantage is that I have to specify the face through a theme. However, this downside can be alleviated by using a default theme. As I am using the `\usepackage{helvet}` in LaTeX, this solution also ensures I am using the identical family as the body text, rather than a (very close) clone.

Using `tikz` appears to be a plausible solution, though is quite unwieldy. (Almost every charts required attention outside knitr.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

<<font_add>>=
library(showtext)
library(sysfonts)
library(knitr)
font.add("helvet", 
         regular = "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb", 
         bold = "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvb8a.pfb", 
         italic = "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvro8a.pfb")

my_pdf <- function(file, width, height){
  pdf(file = file, width = width, height = height
      # ,family = "helvet"
      )
}
@

<<>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height = 1, out.height = "1in", fig.width=5, out.width="5in")
@

\subsubsection*{No distinction between hyphens and negative symbols}
<<pdf, dev='pdf'>>=
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x = 1, y = 1, geom = "blank") + 
  xlab(paste0("RQac 2012-13", "\U2212", "500"))
@

\subsubsection*{Wrong family, though distinction preserved}
<<cairo, dev='cairo_pdf'>>=
qplot(x = 1, y = 1, geom = "blank") + 
  xlab(paste0("RQac 2012-13", "\U2212", "500"))
@

\subsubsection*{Correct family and distinction, though the base family must be called}
<<my_pdf, dev='my_pdf', fig.ext='pdf', fig.showtext=TRUE>>=
qplot(x = 1, y = 1, geom = "blank") + 
  theme_gray(base_family = "helvet") + 
  xlab(paste0("RQac 2012-13", "\U2212", "500"))
@

\end{document}
```

[image: original pdf]

[image: cairo pdf]

[image: showtext]